# bash prompt change [NS:=]

Tags: bash, terminal

I recently  modified my .bashrc in Ubuntu 12.04. I added the following line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/BCAMATH/igarcia/Programs/salome7.2/appli_V7_2_0
```

Which is a existing folder in my computer.

Now, whenever I *source .bashrc* the bash/terminal prompt changes to

```
[NS=:]igarcia@dulx0004:~$
```

And if I source again, then changes to

```
[NS=:][NS=:]igarcia@dulx0004:~$
```

And so on. Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: What's the value of PS1? `echo $PS1`

Comment: Tried this without any problems.  Are you sure the new line is causing the problem?  Try commenting the new line out (prefix with a `#`).

Comment: yes, I am sure it is that line which causes it (but maybe is not the origin of error). If I comment it, the [NS] stuff is not appearing any more. If I do echo $PS1 with the troubeling line commented, the output is `>>echo $PS1` **[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$** If I uncomment, source it, and `>>echo $PS1` **[NS=:][\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$**